# iPhone: cached profile images from the web - how to find out that remote image changed?

Tags: iphone, image, facebook, caching

I'm loading profile pictures from Facebook, cache them on disk and load them into cells of a UITableView.

Now I'm wondering, how I can find out when someone has changed his/her profile picture on Facebook that I have to load the new image from the web instead of using the one cached disk.

The url of the image is always the same. Is there a lightweight way of doing this without downloading the image and comparing it to the local file?

Comment: The url of the image is always the same. Are you sure? It is always different for my application.

Comment: Are you using the Graph API? The URL to request an image is always: graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture

Comment: See my comment below, did you try again on FBConnect library on iphone?

Answer (score 1):

The user profile is available at https://graph.facebook.com//picture.  That URL never changes.

When a request is made to that URL, it redirects to a URL unique to each image.  If your download library properly implements caching and header checking, you will get back a 302 and know that the content hasn't changed.

ASIHTTPRequest is one such library.  It can be configured to download the profile picture, store it on disk, and then only query to see if the image has changed, without downloading the whole image.

Comment: How would you query to see the image changed ?

Comment: One would check for a 302 response.

Comment: sorry, could you be more explicity? How would this work with `AFNetworking 2.0` ?

Comment: I added question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811388/cache-facebook-profile-picture-ios

Answer (score 1):

If you store user profile picture local, get the profile "updated_time" http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
If it's value changed, update the profile picture. You don't need to "cron" this task, or check every time when user connected - subscribe this field to Real-time Updates API.

Answer (score 0):

From my checking, the facebook profile url will change whenever the user changes his profile image. You can check it yourself, but there is no documentation for it. Use it with your own risk:)

Comment: The url of the actual images changes, but not the url I request the image with.

It's always https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture

Comment: oh, that's what makes difference. I used FQL to get the profile url first and then get the real image :(. I will try to take a look in graph api

Comment: I didn't try with graph API for iphone but from my observation in web browser, when I typed: https://graph.facebook.com/vodkhang/picture . It redirects me to a page that contains my image and that link change when the image change. So, what is the response when you send the rest request: https://graph.facebook.com/vodkhang . Will it return you some link or directly respond you with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook Real-time Updates: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

This is not trivial to implement but could be really useful.  When I have the time, I plan to do something like this: set up a server that receives callbacks.  When receiving the callback, capture the time the item was updated.  Then I'd also establish an endpoint that any client could access, passing any entity ID's it wanted, and it'd return the most recent update time.   This could be XML or JSON.  Thus, you'd have to do two things.  1) Initially, add your list of watched entities to my server.  2) To check for updates, make a single call with a list of entity ID's and get back a list of when the ID's were most recently updated, and refresh your cache as appropriate.

It'd be great if I could make such a thing publicly available, huh? :-)